# How to get Rally Stories in closed Projects using pyral

Tags: python, pyral

Is there a way to get Rally Stories for closed Projects using the [pyral](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython) Python library?

When using `rally.get(...)` Stories in closed Projects aren't being returned. Here is the code being used:

```
from pyral import Rally

rally = Rally(...)
rally_id = 'S123456'
response = rally.get('UserStory',
                      query='FormattedID = %s AND Project.State = "Closed"' % rally_id,
                      fetch=True, instance=True)
```

The response contains no results. But, the above example ID `S123456` is a valid Rally Story ID. It's just part of a closed Project.

Also, adding what I think would be the query param syntax to find this Story still didn't work and didn't raise any Python errors either.

Versions of code being used:

- Python 2.7.15
- Pyral 1.4.1 Also back tested in Pyral 1.2.3 and didn't
  work.

Here is the error that I get when calling the above code. The error basically means, the `Rally.get(...)` request failed to find the instance.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/alelevier/Documents/rally_jira_sync/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    697                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    698                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 699             printer.pretty(obj)
    700             printer.flush()
    701             return stream.getvalue()

/Users/alelevier/Documents/rally_jira_sync/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
    401                         if cls is not object \
    402                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 403                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    404 
    405             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

/Users/alelevier/Documents/rally_jira_sync/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    701     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    702     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 703     output = repr(obj)
    704     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    705         if idx:

/Users/alelevier/Documents/rally_jira_sync/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyral/rallyresp.pyc in __repr__(self)
    408             else:
    409                 blurb = "%sResult TotalResultCount: %d  Results: %s" % \
--> 410                          (self.request_type, self.resultCount, self.content['Results'])
    411             return "%s %s" % (self.status_code, blurb)
    412 

KeyError: 'Results'
```

Comment: I just noticed that `getProjects()` also doesn't seem to have a way to specify that closed projects should be returned. There is an open issue for it [here](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython/issues/144).